# Metodo sort() en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una lista de numeros y tengo que mostrarla ordenada.

El siguiente codigo funciona perfecto:

```python
lista.sort()
print(lista)
```

Pero si hago lo siguiente, el resultado es None:

```python
print(lista.sort())
```

A que se debe esta diferencia? Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método `.sort()` de las listas sirve para ordenar la lista "in-situ", pero no retorna nada.

Es uno de los pocos métodos que en lugar de retornar el resultado, alteran directamente el objeto. Por eso, después de haber hecho `lista.sort()` la lista queda ordenada, pero si haces `resultado = lista.sort()` en `resultado` obtendrás `None`, porque ese es el valor retornado por el método (aunque `lista` quedará igualmente ordenada).

Si lo que quieres, **en lugar de alterar la lista**, es recibir una nueva pero que esté ordenada, debes usar `sorted()`, que no es un método de las listas sino una función python. Por ejemplo así:

```
resultado = sorted(lista)
```

En este caso tendrás en `resultado` la lista ordenada. En cambio la variable `lista` seguirá conteniendo la lista desordenada.

Ten en cuenta que si haces simplemente

```
print(sorted(lista))
```

por pantalla verás la lista ordenada, pero en realidad la variable `lista` seguirá como estaba.

Answer (score 1):

Este comportamiento se debe a que el método sort actua sobre la lista sin devolver ningun valor (None), y cuando realizas la impresion `print(objerto.metodo())` se imprime son los valores de retorno del metodo.

para mas informacion:
`help(list.sort)`

The sort is in-place (i.e. the list itself is modified) and stable (i.e. the
order of two equal elements is maintained).